# Discord bot sends 2 messages instead of 1

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot is sending the same message twice, in response to my command.

[image: Image of bot responding twice]

Please help me, I don't know what to do with this problem

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import youtube_dl

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '$')
Bot.remove_command('help')

@Bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {author.mention}")

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator= True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name= "Muted")
    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await ctx.send("Пользователь успешно замьючен")

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator= True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name= "Muted")
    await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
    await ctx.send("Пользователь успешно размьючен")

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator= True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator= True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason="Вы нарушили правила сервера или же админ просто решил вас забанить :)"):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send('Пользователь получил БАН')

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator= True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')
    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user
        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send('Пользователь успешно разбанен')
            return

@Bot.event
async def on_message( message ):
    filter = ['!leave', '!play','!skip']
    for word in filter:

            if message.content.count(word) > 0:
                print('%s bad word' % (message.author.id))
                await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
                await message.author.send('Просьба писать команды для бота в #music')
            await Bot.process_commands(message)

@Bot.event
async def on_message( message ):
    filter = ['!leave', '!play','!skip']
    for word in filter:

            if message.content.count(word) > 0:
                print('%s bad word' % (message.author.id))
                await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
                await message.author.send('Просьба писать команды для бота в #music')
            await Bot.process_commands(message)

@Bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f'Привет, {member.name}, добро пожаловать на наш сервер!')
    return

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await Bot.change_presence(status=None, activity=discord.Game("Steins;Gate 0"))
    print("Bot is ready!")

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator= True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))
    await ctx.channel.send('Сообщения успешно удалены')

Bot.run("Token")
```

Comment: Don't you actually have on_message 2x?

Comment: I don't get the latest part of your question? is it latin? could you provide us that in english, so everyone could benefit from the question and evt. the answer?

Comment: @dboy - The end text is [Lorem ipsum](https://www.lipsum.com/) - dummy text.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Yes. Not sure how it ended up there, but I literally can't edit the question to remove it because without it the system complains about there being too much code and not enough explanation.

Comment: Looks like you created a new question. I'll move my answer over to the new one.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere: nice, always learn something new..

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you ran the program twice, to make sure this doesn't happen, I suggest implementing a kill switch so every time when you rerun the program you activate the kill switch first on Discord then run the program again.
An example of the killswitch that I made is something like this:

```
@client.command()
async def quit(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Shutting down the bot")
    return await client.logout() # this just shuts down the bot.
```