# My discord.py bot with chat-filter event sends 2 or more messages instead of 1

Tags: python, bots, discord

Not so long ago added in my discord bot chat-filter ,which delete messages which i dont want to see.But i have a problem with this.Before this new event my bot sends on the command $hello 1 message(hello,{me}),but with this chat filter he sends 2 or more questions(Number of posts = number of banned words).Can u heip me with this.

[image]

```py
@Bot.event
async def on_message( message ):
    filter = ['!leave', '!play','!skip']
    for word in filter:

        if word in message.content:
            print('%s bad word' % (message.author.id))
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            await message.author.send('Просьба писать команды для бота в #music')
        await Bot.process_commands(message)
```

This is the chat filter code that the problem is.
I think that because of this filter, all my code compiles three times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot sends 2 messages instead of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552504/discord-bot-sends-2-messages-instead-of-1)

Answer (score 0):

Guessing this is a dup of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61552504/1935238)

Since you have 2 `on_message()` functions only the second one will be processed. You should remove one.

You issue with the multiple messages is because you are processing your `await bot.process_commands(message)` command in your `for` loop. Based on having 3 bad words you have 3 messages.

Try de-indenting your `await bot.process_commands(message)` to be even with your `for word in filter`.